# Why would importing uuid cause uwsgi daemon to hang?

Tags: python, uwsgi, wsgi

I'm able to execute the following WSGI program using uwsgi (when uwsgi is running as systemd).

```
def application(env, start_response):
  start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
  return [b"Hello world"]
```

However, if I attempt to import the uuid module, the program will hang and eventually time out. But running the program with uwsgi directly will work:

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http -w myapp
```

Why would uuid cause uwsgi to hang?

Answer (score -1):

In my INI file, setting threads = 2 is what caused importing uuid to hang.